# passing value into a range defined in jinja2 via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I would like to pass the variable vrf_instances to Jinja2 template via Python. Something like below. Doesn't seem to work for me. Is it even possible?

For example -

```
{% for n in range(1, {{ vrf_instances }} ) -%}
```

Python code:

```
vrf_instances = int(input('Enter number of VRF instances:'))
config = template.render(vrf_instances = vrf_instances)
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{...}}` can't be nested within a `{%...%}` block. You can reference the variables directly instead:

```
{% for n in range(1, vrf_instances) -%}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, `{{...}}` can't be nested within a `{%...%}`
I would suggest you try something like

```
{% for n in range(1, vrf_instances) %}
     #Do something  
{% endfor %}
```

Since [list comprehensions are not supported in Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/faq/#isn-t-it-a-terrible-idea-to-put-logic-into-templates)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Much appreciated.